# Sysprepping Windows Server 2012, how do I avoid plug and play drivers installed by VMware Tools being removed?

Tags: windows-server-2008, vmware-vsphere, windows-server-2012, sysprep

I am sysprepping Windows Server 2012 Standard to be used as a VM template. I want to preserve drivers installed by VMWare Tools such that the mouse won't lag in new installations. If I just run a normal `sysprep /oobe /generalize`, the drivers will get lost. The mouse will lag. Repairing the VMWare Tools installation fixes the issue.

In Windows Server 2008 R2 I solved this issue by telling sysprep to preserve plug and play drivers, but I have no idea how to do this when sysprepping 2012.

Answer (score 1):

> You can persist device drivers when you run the Sysprep command
>   together with the /generalize option. To do this, specify the
>   PersistAllDeviceInstalls setting in the Microsoft-Windows-PnPSysprep
>   component. During the specialize configuration pass, Plug and Play
>   scans the computer for devices, and then installs device drivers for
>   the detected devices. By default, the computer removes these device
>   drivers from the system when you generalize the system. If you set the
>   Microsoft-Windows-PnPSysprep\PersistAllDeviceInstalls setting to true
>   in an answer file, Sysprep doesn't remove the detected device drivers.

[Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824849.aspx#bkmk_3)